# Use animatedVectorDrawable in custom view

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I know we can draw a vector drawable like this on canvas:

```
vectorDrawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
vectorDrawable.draw(canvas);
```

but Is it possible to use animatedVectorDrawables in custom view?

Comment: sure: call `View#setBackground` method

Comment: no not like the background I want AnimatedVectorDrawable for a part of Custom view

Comment: so read `android.graphics.drawable.Drawable` documentation and ^F `callback`

Comment: btw base `android.view.View` class implements `Drawable.Callback` so you can use any `View` as a callback

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, and looks like the snippet you have would work.  Be sure to set bounds and call the `start()` method on the drawable to start the animation.

```
class MyCustomView : View {

  lateinit var animVectDrawable: AnimatedVectorDrawable

  fun startAnim() {
    animVectDrawable.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom)
    animVectDrawable.start()
    shouldDrawAnim = true
  }

  override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas)
    if (shouldDrawAnim) {
      animVectDrawable.draw(canvas)
    }
  }
}
```